# Why should I specify a lifetime annotation when typing a struct in a function declaration?

Tags: rust

"The Rust Programming Language" shows the following example of using lifetime annotations with a function:

```
fn longest<'a>(x: &'a str, y: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

If I want to call such a function, I can just call it without anything special. If I want to define a struct, I can do a similar thing:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct News<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
    text: &'a str
}
```

But when using it, as in this example of `rocket` route, I have to "type" the struct with lifetime annotation

```
#[get("/submit", data = "<n>")]
async fn submit(n: Json<News<'_>>) -> Status {
    print!("{:#?}", n);
    Status::Ok
}
```

Why do I have to add these "types" when writing a signature? It looks like something compiler can (as when I call a function) figure out by itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, lets see if this questions throw some light on that: do you realize that in your example enum **both** str references needs to live for the same lifeframe? What happen if you do not want that?

Comment: Well, yes, I see that. However, in the struct definition, both have lifetime of `'a`. Doesn't that mean that I shouldn't even be able to create a struct using strings with different lifetimes, let alone pass it to a function?

Comment: Exactly, both String references would have to be created in the same scope for example, or at least lifetimes will be the sorter of both of them. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Netwave It's not true that both string references need to have the same lifetime. The compiler will simply infer `'a` to mean the shorter of the two lifetimes of whatever string slices you use to initialize the struct. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73cccbc7c06a1f28a09aa70e2f5b7bbd))

Comment: Ok, so, if compiler won't let me write code which creates struct with broken lifetimes, why would I specify the lifetime modifier in the function declaration? It's not like I can call the function with a struct with "broken" lifetimes

Comment: @keddad You can specify the lifetime parameter if you want to, but you don't have to: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83803be3f6ba3803b561a64519e12fe1

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yeah, I puntualized that in "or at least lifetimes will be the sorter of both of them".

Comment: Not really. In the example `submit()` function, if I remove lifetime modifiers, it fails to compile. It might be connected to how `rocket` works, but I can't quite understand it. Here is compiler [log](https://gist.github.com/keddad/352830301460ff8cb69bcab3967a03ba).

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of `async` functions: https://docs.rs/async-trait/0.1.41/async_trait/#elided-lifetimes

Comment: @interjay: I don't know if it is a limitation or a concious design decision, because eliding lifetimes in function arguments of type struct is considered a bad idea, in hindsight.